# Best way to store files on social network

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, bigdata

Im using **`Mongo database` , `PHP` , `Nodes.js`** and have a problem with saving files .

since : Files size may be more than 1PB (1000 TB) .

In my mind two ways to do it :

1. Save files on server as file ( jpg , mp3 , mp4 , ... )
2. Save files on Mongo Database on post ( bit , ... )

Witch is better ?

If you have other solution please let me know about that .

Comment: If you have thus much data then you need to setup our own datacentre.. And yah for that you need billion of dollars...

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI We have no problem with that .

Comment: For large data storage, you usually don't want to store the giant data itself in a database.  Instead, store the large files in the file system (probably across multiple drives/servers) and you can store a filename/volume reference in the database along with any other relevant meta data.

Comment: Then start building your datacenter  @Ghorbanzadeh

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI - You can have that much storage pretty quickly via AWS.  No need to build your own data center any more.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI our problem is not building data center . our problem is how to store files on servers . Please don't spam .

Comment: For such big case, you could check how Instagram distributes its images around the globe. [Here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-software-architecture-of-Instagram) is some old discussion about their architecture. You may google something more up-to-date if you think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large data storage, you usually don't want to store the giant data files (like images, music files, video files) itself in a database.

Instead, store the large files in the file system (probably across multiple drives/servers) and you can store a filename/volume reference in the database along with any other relevant meta data.

This will also allow you to stream these files directly from the file system to the user (upon browser request) more efficiently rather than having to translate them from database format into what you would send the user.

And, if you're going to have a ton of storage, you should probably design your system from the beginning to be able to easily use cloud storage services like AWS.  I know some of the people behind a popular photo sharing service and they switched over to using AWS for image storage, saved a lot of money and got better performance and easier redundancy.  If you aren't already planning to start with a hosting service, you should be thinking about how you would move at least part of your service to one over time.

Comment: thank you please let me know about AWS . What is that exactly ?

Comment: @Ghorbanzadeh - I take it you must be a bit new to building a hosted server business.  AWS is Amazon Web Services, the Goliath of cloud services.  Hugely successful, used by thousands of companies.  Many startups these days never build their own hosting environment, they just use auto-scaling cloud services such as AWS, Microsoft Azure or Google Cloud Platform.  And many much larger companies are finding it a more effective way to run their own infrastructure.  You can just use storage services or you can put all your infrastructure there including your server processes.